# Strange const char* function return value behaviour

Tags: c++

This is the entire program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const char* str_c = "\0";

const char* function() {
    string str_cpp = "John Doe";
    str_c = str_cpp.c_str();
    cout << str_cpp.c_str() << "\n";
    cout << str_c << "\n";
    return str_c;
}

int main() {
    cout << function() << "\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what it returns:

- John Doe
- John Doe
- ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

I have no clue why the string to which `str_c` points suddenly went missing. Is it because its contents were created within `function()` and therefore had a shorter lifespan?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `"\0"` should just be `""`. The compiler will put the nul terminator in; you don't need to code it explicitly.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I'm on mac, I compiled with g++ and clang++ and it worked. I had to remove the system call (mac doesn't have pause command).

Comment: @Dan  Why is `std::endl` instead of `\n` a better practice? `std:endl` flushes the output stream which is costly (and rarely needed).
[Use of std::endl in place of '\n', encouraged by some sources, may significantly degrade output performance.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)